# What is the correct OAuth2 flow to use where user is already authenticated

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect, pingfederate

I am still trying to understand the OAuth2 flows and how it all works together, so apologies in advance if this example is confusing.

The way I understand the OAuth2 authorization flow is:

1. User goes to a url for a website ([www.somesite.com](http://www.somesite.com))
2. User is redirected to an authorization server, like PingFederate, where the user will authenticate.
3. Once authenticated, the user will be redirected back to the initial site with an authorization code.
4. etc...

Here's where my situation is different. I cannot redirect my users to an authorization server to log in because my company uses a third-party application framework that authenticates users to a proprietary database. Therefore, my users are already authenticated.
Also, my users will never need to allow another application to access their contacts, etc... like all of the OAuth2 examples I've seen.

But, I still need to request authorization tokens (in my case, JWTs) that are individual for each user so that they can pass the token to services that may be called from my primary web app.

The Client Credentials flow doesn't seem to make sense to use because as I understand it, it's more of a machine-to-machine flow.

What flow can I use that will allow me to request authorization tokens from my auth server that contain user-specific attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What flow can I use that will allow me to request authorization tokens
> from my auth server that contain user-specific attributes?

If you trust your client app from security point of view then you can use `Resource Owner Password Flow`. Your client code/app has to take user credentials and submit it to authorization server with other details require for this flow. The authorization server will issue a oauth `access token`. If you want oauth `authorization server` to issue `JWT` then you've to implement some code to enhance access token.

Comment: When you say that the client has to take the user credentials and submit it to the server, I assume you mean the authorization server. If that's true, I cannot do that, because my authorization server cannot verify the credentials as the credentials are stored in a proprietary database.

Comment: No. I said, your client app will take the credentials that's why I mentioned about trust. BTW, how you want the authorization server to issue token without validating the credentials?

Answer (score 0):

You should still redirect the user, and use the [Code Flow](https://curity.io/resources/learn/openid-code-flow/). The Authorization Server (AS) needs to be adapted to verify usernames and passwords entered in its login form by connecting to your custom database.

Any good AS will support this via its extensibility features. Look for options such as these:

- A credential validator that uses JDBC to connect to a database
- A credential validator that uses a custom HTTP client to connect to an API